# Validation Message from the fleUploadListener not showing inside a `<p:dialog>`

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a `<p:dialog>` in which I am uploading a file.

```
<p:dialog id="uploadFileDialog"
        header="Upload File" widgetVar="uploadFileDialog" 
        modal="true" minHeight="40">
  <p:messages id="fileUploadMsgs" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"  
              closable="true" redisplay="false"/>
     <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" mode="advanced"
                multiple="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(docx|doc|pdf)$/"
                fileUploadListener="#{testMB.uploadFileListener}"
                auto="false" onstart="PF('ajaxStatusDialog').show()"
                oncomplete="PF('ajaxStatusDialog').hide()">    
        </p:fileUpload>
</p:dialog>
```

In the file Upload Listener I'm looking if a file already exists in the Database, if it does I need to throw and error back in the dialog box. I tried setting `globalOnly="true"` and passing the client id as null in `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage`, but it didn't work. I even tried passing the id of `<p:messages>` in addMessage, that didn't work too. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: My code for fileUploadListener

```
    public void uploadFileListener(FileUploadEvent event){
            boolean success = false;
        List<Files> fileList = getDbFilesList();            
           if(fileList == null){
                success = handleDocumentUpload(event);
            }else{
                success = false;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        "fileUploadMsgs",
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                "Error : ",
                                "File Already Exists."));
            }
        }
```

I am using primefaces 5.2 and jsf 2.2. Thanks!

Comment: You **ARE** passing the id of the `p:messages`. That is wrong, it should be the id of the fileUpload. And you are saying it works outside a `p:dialog`? At least that is what your title and code hint to

Comment: a. If you are using @Kukeltje suggestion set `globalOnly='false'` to the messages component. if not use b.`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        "null,...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to make it work. Please see the updated code below.

```
<p:dialog id="uploadFileDialog"
        header="Upload File" widgetVar="uploadFileDialog" 
        modal="true" minHeight="40">
<h:form id="testForm>  
<p:messages id="fileUploadMsgs" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"  
              closable="true" redisplay="true"/>
     <p:fileUpload id="uploadFile" mode="advanced"
                multiple="false" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(docx|doc|pdf)$/"
                fileUploadListener="#{testMB.uploadFileListener}"
                auto="false" onstart="PF('ajaxStatusDialog').show()"
                oncomplete="PF('ajaxStatusDialog').hide()" update="fileUploadMsgs">    
        </p:fileUpload>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The code for File upload listener is as below :

```
public void uploadFileListener(FileUploadEvent event){
            boolean success = false;
        List<Files> fileList = getDbFilesList();            
           if(fileList == null){
                success = handleDocumentUpload(event);
            }else{
                success = false;
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                        "testForm:uploadFile",
                        new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                                "Error : ",
                                "File Already Exists."));
            }
        }
```